# ASP .NET Session Cookie Issues in SAML Single Sign-on

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

I am working on a web project (IIS) targeting .NET 4.0.  I am attempting to connect to a third-party using SAML for single sign-on.

My product is set up in two iframes - top for the menus, bottom for the content.  When I try to load the third-party content in the bottom frame it fails because it is missing the session cookie.  If I set the third-party site to open in a new tab instead of the bottom frame the session cookie is present and correct.

I watched both in Fiddler.  The third-party's initial response is a result 302 and sets 2 cookies - .AspNetCore.Session and a server version.  This happens in both scenarios.

In subsequent communication my site is always sending the server version cookie.  But it only sends the .AspNetSore.Session cookie when set to open in a new tab.  I get no errors other than the third-party site rejecting the connection due to the missing session cookie (in the iframe).

My site has its own ASP.NET_SessionId cookie.  We are nowhere near the limit on cookies and I have the same problem even when I clear all cookies before trying so I'm wondering if there is a conflict between my session cookie and the third-party's session cookie.

The SAML tool I'm using is ComponentSpace and their support has confirmed that it sends the message via the browser, which can then be used to invoke session state.  My piece of code that performs the single sign-on is one line - invoking the ComponentSpace library.  If I check the response after that line is completed the third-party's session cookie is already gone.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is directly related to the SAML library. What I suggest doing is creating a small test project that demonstrates the issue. Zip it up and send it to ComponentSpace so they can see exactly what's happening and can reproduce the issue.

Comment: For anyone interested - the problem turned out to be because our application uses iFrames and the vendor is sending the samesite=lax parameter in their cookie.  The vendor won't remove that for security reasons so the solution was to open their site in a new window.